# how to save last entered edit text value in Android App?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview

I am creating a simple android app with login credentials as username and password in edit text.
How can i save last entered username and password in app , when user try to relogin.  How should i handle it. Do i have to store them in android app or it can be taken care of my android. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<EditText
   android:id = "@+id/editText2"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:inputType = "textPassword" />

<EditText
   android:id = "@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: You can try to use shared preferences, and save values by key = value

Comment: will it going to save after reloading entire app

Comment: after reinstall - no, after reopen - yes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

But it's not safe to store credentials raw.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways:

- store data in [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) locally.
- save data locally again but with databases like [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).
- make online database and connect to it with [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or something
  like that. (this one is a good choice when it comes to bigger projects)